# How bad is it to use @POST to retrieve data?

Tags: java, rest, post, get

I am currently using a @POST web service to retrieve data.
My idea, at the beginning, was to pass a map of parameters. Then my function, on the server side, would take care of reading the needed parameters in the map and return the response.
This is to prevent having a big number of function almost identical on the server side.

But if I understood correctly, @POST should be use for creation of content.

So my question: Is it a big programming mistake to use @POST for data retrieval?
Is it better to create 1 web service per use case, even if it is a lot?

Thanks.
Romain.

Comment: How is that a mistake? If that is what your application expects, go for it!

Comment: I dont see any thing wrong with it

Comment: It is only a "mistake" in terms of pure REST, where the HTTP verbs are assigned the semantics you mention. So, while it may confuse RESTnik's, it'll work just fine for you :-)

Comment: It's not as bad as using GET to modify data ...

Comment: So it is technically not an issue. The piece of code will work fine.

However, it will remove the advantages of using HTTP verbs, so not the best choice architecture-wise.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POST is used to say that you are submitting data.
GET requests can be bookmarked, POST can't. Before there were single page web appliations we used post-redirect-get to accepta data submission and display a bookmakable page.

If you use POST to retrieve data then [web-caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) doesn't work, because the caching code doesn't cache POSTS, it expects POST to mean it needs to invalidate its cache. If you split your services out use-case-wise and use GET then you can have something like [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) cache the responses.

You may not need to implement caching right now, but it would be good to keep the option open. Making your services act in a compliant way means you can get leverage from existing tools and infrastructure (which is a selling point of REST).

Answer (score -3):

```
doGet();
```

Called by the server (via the service method) to allow a servlet to handle a GET request.

```
doPost()
```

Called by the server (via the service method) to allow a servlet to handle a POST request.

No issues with them.Both will handle your request.